# Jquery UI draggable/droppable, check drag item class in droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 3 separate (with separate class names) items I am dropping into a big div. I need the drop function to run something different depending on which draggble item I drop into the droppable.

Here is my code.

```
$(".gridster").droppable({
        accept: ".dragExist,.dragDefault, .dragLaunch",
        hoverClass: "drop-state",
        drop: function(event,ui){
            var currentId = $(ui.draggable).attr("class");
             if(currentId == "dragExist"){
                 gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li>new Widget', 1, 1]);
                 console.log(event);
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
        }
    });
```

If i could get the first if statement to work I would add in the other 2 classes, but I don't seem to be getting this correct. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add a class suppose 'selected-item' on mousedown event of each draggable element. Then in the drop event you can easily identify the element which was dragged using the 'selected-item' class and at the end remove the class.